# How to delete/detect expired session in node?

Tags: javascript, node.js, session

I have a livechat system based on node.js. I let the user sends to the sever a signal to tell the server he/she is online, so I will extend their session to prevent it from expiring. The default expire time is 10 seconds.

Now, I noticed that the session does not get removed after it expires. So when I call function:

```
Hub.prototype.find = function(username, fn) {
    for(var sid in this.sessions) {
        var session = this.sessions[sid],
            sess_username = session.data('username');
        if(sess_username == username) {
            fn(session);
            return;
        }
    }
    fn(false);
};
```

It still returns the session, means that they can still find the session in the this.sessions array. How can I let it return false when the found session is expired? How can I tell?

Thank you very much!

Comment: Where did you let expire it? Are you using any session management framework?

Comment: @Bergi No. I let it expire by setting the exp date like this `var d = new Date();
var n = d.getTime() + 10;

    req.sessionID.expires = n;`